# How to get SQL Server Report Server URL?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Can anyone please tell me how to find the installed SQL Server 2005/2008/2008R2 report server URL in C#, without knowing the installed SQL instance name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that you can get it from the rsreportserver.config file.

I don't think you can get it from the ReportServer database or from the registry...